# Logical error in my implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: c++, dijkstra

I've been working on Dijkstra's algorithm for quite some time, trying to figure out the shortest distance between to vertices by using an adjacency matrix. It seems that most of the algorithm works fine, but I get some problem when it's time to move on tho the next vertex. Here's my code:

```
/*Declarations and initialization*/
int* result;
int dist[this->nr_airport];
int unvisited[this->nr_airport];
int cur_vertex = source;
int check_dist = 0;
bool check_val_found = false;
for(int i=0 ; i<this->nr_airport ; i++)
{
     dist[i] = -1;      //-1 represents infinity
     unvisited[i] = i;  //the set of all unvisited nodes
}
dist[source] = 0;

/*Determining distances*/
for(int i=0 ; i<this->nr_airport ; i++)
{
    if(unvisited[i]!=-1 && this->matrix[cur_vertex][i]>0)   //Check if node is unvisited and neighbour to cur_vertex
    {
        if(dist[i]>=dist[cur_vertex]+this->matrix[cur_vertex][i] || dist[i]==-1)    //Check distance
        {
            dist[i] = dist[cur_vertex]+this->matrix[cur_vertex][i]; //Assign new distance
        }
    }
}

/*Setting the new vertex*/
for(int i=0 ; i<this->nr_airport ; i++)
{
    if(this->matrix[cur_vertex][i]>0 && unvisited[i]!=-1 && dist[i]>0)
    {
        if(!check_val_found)
        {
            check_dist = dist[i];
            cur_vertex = i;
            check_val_found = true;
        }
        if(dist[i]<check_dist)
        {
            check_dist = dist[i];
            cur_vertex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly I loop through the matrix to determine the shortest distances of the current vertex' neighbors and assign that value to dist[]. I do this if the vertex is unvisited (unvisited[]!=-1) and if the matrix value indicates that it's a neighbor.

Then, to check which vertex is next, I loop through all the vertices and check their distance from the start node, which is held by dist[]. If a vertex is already visited (unvisited[]==-1) or if the vertex is the current vertex or not a neighbor to the current vertex (this->matrix[][]==0 or this->matrix[][]==-1), then it won't check since that vertex can't be the next one to examine.

Something goes wrong here, because when I run the program, it seems that firstly, it doesn't check with all the vertices it should, and secondly, it checks with some vertices it shouldn't; i've had the problem that I go from one vertex to another vertex which is in fact *not* a neighbor of the current vertex. I have checked the matrix, and it's correct.

Comment: Where do you use the value in the adjacency matrix to update the new dist?

Comment: @izomorphius I've now added the code where I use the matrix to determine the distances.

Comment: this code will go to negative dist really fast. You should set dist[0] = 0.  Also where you do this check `dist[i]>=dist[cur_vertex]+this->matrix[cur_vertex][i]` check if dist[curr_vertex] is < 0 just in case.

Comment: @izomorphius Could you please explain how it will go to negative distances? I've never encountered that behavior and I can't see how it could do that; it only checks if value in the matrix is positive, and dist[cur_vertex] will have a value assigned to it already, so I can't see how it can become negative.

Comment: First iteration. dist[0] = -1. As dist[1] = dist[2] = ... = dist[n] =- 1 you go into the if. So the distance to each vertex will become matrix[curr_vertex][i]-1. If the matrix is 0 or -1 or whatever you use to indicate no edge - there you have it.

Comment: @izomorphius Sorry, missed a line of code. After the for-loop in the initializations, I set dist[source] to be 0. Then I do not get that problem.

Comment: I am sorry I do not have time to write a complete answer now. Still here is the essense - when selecting current vertex you should look for any vertex with small enough distance not only the ones connected to current vertex.